# How to orderby meta_value_num with dollar ($) sign

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query, sort, wp-parse-args

The custom fields all have prices including $ signs, and a dot as separator.

```
$theQuery = new WP_Query(array(
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_key' => 'price',
'order' => ASC  
));
```

All formatted like this:

$24.95
$190.00
$1.40

They won't sort correctly due to the dollar sign, is it possible to ignore or remove the first character / $ sign in this WP_Query?

Comment: Why can't you enter a number without a dollar sign and then display the dollar sign on the front-end if needed? I am not sure, but I suspect this would be a very complicated query.

Comment: I understand but all custom fields are created by a plugin and inputs these with a $ sign, and the database already has a lot of posts.

Comment: A bad plugin, I'm afraid. :(

Comment: I agree with Mayeenul. I would contact the developer and ask him/her to stop saving the $.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `posts_orderby` filter:

```
function wpse155827_posts_orderby_price( $orderby ) {
    return str_replace( 'wp_postmeta.meta_value', 'substr(wp_postmeta.meta_value, 1)', $orderby );
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse155827_posts_orderby_price' );
$theQuery = new WP_Query( array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
) );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse155827_posts_orderby_price' );
```

Comment: I tested but it won't order them correctly, I will test it again with the exact query your posted because mine has some other arguments too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `post_clauses` filter to create some custom SQL:

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse155827_price_sort', 10, 2 );

function wpse155827_price_sort( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    $orderby = $wp_query->get( 'orderby' ); 
    $order = ( $wp_query->get( 'order' ) == 'desc') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    if( 'price' === $orderby ) {
        $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} price ON( {$wpdb->posts }.ID = price.post_id AND price.meta_key = 'price') ";
        $clauses['orderby'] = " CONVERT( REPLACE(price.meta_value, '$', ''), DECIMAL(13,2) ) " . $order;
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

Basically, this is a filter that creates custom mySQL code in your query whenever you set `orderby` to `price`.  in the mySQL code, it takes the meta value, removes the `$` sign, them converts it into a decimal.  This will allow it to sort properly now.

Comment: This needs into functions.php? I tested but it won't order them correctly.

Comment: Does it order it the same way as before?

Comment: Yes. Maybe a solution would be to regenerate a new custom field using your filtering in functions.php and then use that as the meta_key to sort on. Does your code work at your end? Maybe some custom code in my theme prevents it to work.